# How do I set up a port such that when someone netcats to it, a script is run

Tags: linux, bash, networking

So for example, when a user netcats to port 7896, a script which asks for a user input will run.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this. Create `listener` script

```
$ cat listener
#!/bin/bash
port=7896
input=$(nc -l -p $port) || exit $?
./test ${input:-empty}
```

Create `test` script

```
$ cat test 
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
./listener
```

Run `listener`

```
./listener
```

And in another terminal run

```
port=7896
nc -q0 localhost $port 2> /dev/null <<< "hello"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a server that executes `foo.sh` when someone connects.

**server.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

while [[ 1 ]]; do
    ncat -l -p 7896 -e foo.sh
done
```

**foo.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n 'prompt> '
while IFS= read -r cmd
do
    echo "got >$cmd<"
    echo -n 'prompt> '
done
```

A sample session:

```
$ ncat localhost 7896
prompt> Hello world
got >Hello world<
prompt> <CTRL-D>
$
```

Comment: What `nc` version do you use? I don't have `-e` `option nc: invalid option -- 'e'` on `Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS, netcat-openbsd 1.187-1ubuntu0.1`

Comment: @Ivan I now made it work on Ubuntu 18.04 too which has `Ncat: Version 7.60 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )`.

Comment: @Ivan I'm not sure I had to do anything, but perhaps I did in the past. `sudo apt install nmap` should give you `ncat` (and other `nmap` utilities).

Comment: Oh, got it it's not `nc` it's `ncat`)

Comment: @Ivan Yes, which on Fedora (which I used when I first wrote the answer) is the same thing :-) I just have to change to `ncat` to make it work on Ubuntu too.

Comment: I'm surprised no one has mentioned inetd.  It's made for this exact purpose.

Comment: @JeffSpaulding Why is that a comment to my answer? :-)  Please go ahead and write an answer. I may upvote it.